Persist Custom Profile Attributes Across User Logins/App Reinstallations in Mesibo
I'm developing archive, mute, and pin features for my messenger app using the Mesibo Android Kotlin SDK. However, I’ve noticed that these settings don’t persist between login and logout cycles. Is there a way to make Mesibo retain these custom values across sessions?
profile?.apply {
// Toggle mute status
val newMuteStatus = !getBoolean("muted", false)
setBoolean("muted", newMuteStatus)

// Toggle archive status
val archiveStatus = !getBoolean("archived", false)
setBoolean("archived", newMuteStatus)
save()



Let me clarify how the profile synchronization and persistence works:
All settings in your self profile including custom fields synchronize to the server and persist across devices when you save them. However, any changes made to other users' profiles are naturally not synced and are saved on the local device only.
https://docs.mesibo.com/api/users-and-profiles/
However, mesibo does synchronize a few settings you make on others' profiles, such as favorite, archived, etc. You can use following functions:
archive()
isArchived()
favorite()
isFavorite()

I understand you need similar settings for mute and pin features as well. While these flags aren't currently synced by default, we can certainly add support for additional flags like these. If you prefer that, I can submit an enhancement request for it. Please file a support ticket with your account details.
We do not recommend using SharedPreferences or any platform specific mechanism as it will not be synced across other platforms/devices Mesibo supports (iOS, Javascript, etc).

I have tried the archive() function; it works fine for individual user profiles (persists between sessions) but doesn't work for group profiles.

If you just want to save simple Data like a Bool a String or an Integer i would recommend using Datastore. Not Shared Preferences apparently as pointed out in the Comment below.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore
If you want to Store more complex Data like a hole Userprofil oder another complex Data structure you should use a Database concept like Room.
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/

SharedPreferences are no longer recommended, you should be switching to data stores instead.
